# Guessing game with minimum guesses used not working in Java

Tags: java

I'm creating a guessing game in Java using NetBeans. The guessing game allows the user to guess a number between 1 and 10. Each round they have 5 chances to guess the number. There are three rounds in the game. After the user finishes the game, stats are outputted with the minimum # of guess and maximum # of guesses.

The minimum guesses isn't working and it always outputs 1. Right now, I have the program set up so that it keeps track of how many times the user guesses per round. After each round, it compares this value to the min value and max value. The minGuess is set as 5 since it isn't possible to guess more than 5 times. The maxGuess is set as 1 since they will always guess one time or more than one time.

```
static void numberGuess(int guess, int randNum) {                              //creating a method to check if the user has guessed the correct number or if the guess should be higher or lower

if (guess < 0 | guess > 10) {
    System.out.println("Please enter a valid number between 1 and 10."); 
}
else if (guess == randNum) {
    System.out.println("You guessed the number correctly");
}
else if (guess < randNum) {
    System.out.println("Guess is too low");
}
else if (guess > randNum) {
    System.out.println("Guess is too high");
}




}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
   /*Rational:  This program allows a user to guess a number between 1 and 10 five times per round. There are three rounds in one game.
                 The program then outputs the stats for the game. 
    */
   //declaration 
   int userGuess;            //creates a spot in memory for these variables 
   int numOfGuess = 0; 
   int invalidGuess = 0; 
   int minGuess = 5; 
   int maxGuess = 1; 
   int average; 

   Scanner Input = new Scanner (System.in);  //creates an object in the scanner clas
   //execution
   System.out.println("Welcome to Super Guessing Game! Guess a random number between 1 and 10. There are three rounds with one guess each.");
   loopOne:                                     //labels the loop as loopTwo
   for (int x = 1;  x <= 3; x= x + 1 ) {        //runs the loop for three rounds 
       System.out.println(" ");
       System.out.println("Round " + x);
       System.out.println("To exit the game at any point, enter a negative 1");
       System.out.println(" ");

       int randNum;
       randNum = 1 + (int)(Math.random() * ((10 - 1) + 1));     //generates the random number 


       loopTwo:                                        //labels the loop as loopTwo
       for (int y = 1; y <= 5; y= y + 1) {             //runs the loop five times (five guesses per round)
           numOfGuess = numOfGuess + 1;               //counts number of guesses user has made
           System.out.println("Guess " + y + " out of 5");
           System.out.println("Please guess a number between 1 and 10: ");
           userGuess = Input.nextInt();
           if (userGuess == -1){                       //sentinel to let the user quit at any time
           System.out.println("Thank you for playing");
           break loopOne;                             //breaks out of the loops if the user wants to stop playing
           }

           numberGuess(userGuess, randNum);      //calls the numberGuess method
           if (y < minGuess)                    //compares to see if the minimum number of guesses is less that the number of guesses the user has made this round
               minGuess = y; 
           if (y > maxGuess)                    //compares to see if the maximum number of guesses is greater than the number of guesses that the user has made this round 
               maxGuess = y; 


            if (userGuess <1 | userGuess > 10) {      //keeps track of invalid guesses
               invalidGuess = invalidGuess + 1; 
           }

           if (userGuess == randNum) {            //exits the round if the user guesses correctly
               break; 
           }
       }

   }
   average = numOfGuess / 3;              //calculates the average number of guesses
   System.out.println("Thanks for playing!");     //outputs the following 
   System.out.println("");
   System.out.println("Number of Guesses Made: " + numOfGuess); 
   System.out.println("Average Number of Guesses: " + average);  
   System.out.println("Number of Invalid Guesses: " + invalidGuess);
   System.out.println("Minimum Guesses Used: " + minGuess);
   System.out.println("Maximum Guesses Used: " + maxGuess);

}
```

}

Comment: Just wondering, isn't `((10 - 1) + 1)` is just `10`?

Comment: The random number part is working it's just the minimum number of guesses that isn't working.

Comment: Yeah. It surely will. I was just wondering if there is any trick in writing `10` like that! :)

Comment: I believe if you write 10 by itself it generates random numbers between 0 and 9. You would have to add one to the random integer. But by writing 10 this way it makes sure that the numbers generated are between 1 and 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

y starts at one, and is never less than one, thus minGuess is always one.

```
   for (int y = 1; y <= 5; y= y + 1) {             
   ...
       if (y < minGuess)                    
           minGuess = y; 
   ...
   }
```

Consider only updating minGuess and maxGuess upon a successful guess.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement is at the wrong place.

Your asking every time. also if the user isnt guessing the right number.

so just put it in ur numberguess method:

```
else if (guess == randNum) {
 System.out.println("You guessed the number correctly");
 if (y < minGuess)                    //compares to see if the minimum number of guesses is less that the number of guesses the user has made this round
   minGuess = y; 
 if (y > maxGuess)                    //compares to see if the maximum number of guesses is greater than the number of guesses that the user has made this round 
   maxGuess = y; 
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll give it a try.